# How to assign several different strings to a char* array

Tags: c++

guys I was trying to put several different strings like these:

```
cap
to
cat
card
two
too
up
boat
boot
```

into a char* array like this:

```
char* result[9]
```

and after assigning every one of those strings into the array with a for loop, I found that all the elements in the array is the same, which is "boot".

My code and result are down here:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    char* result[9];
    for(int counter=0;counter<9;counter++)
   {
        string temp;
        getline(cin,temp);
        result[counter]=(char*) temp.c_str();
        cout<<result[counter]<<endl;//correct
    }
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
for(int counter=0;counter<9;counter++)
    cout<<result[counter]<<endl;//false
}
```

This line works well,

```
 cout<<result[counter]<<endl;//correct
```

and it prints all the different words like:

```
cap
to
cat
card
two
too
up
boat
boot
```

but somehow, this line

```
 cout<<result[counter]<<endl;//false
```

it only prints "boot" nine times. I really can't see the reason here and I am hoping you guys can give me a hand, thx!

Comment: Your code has a deeper problem. You are assigning the address of a local variable that outside the first loop will be invalid.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    string temp;
    getline(cin,temp);
    result[counter]=(char*) temp.c_str();   /* 1 */
    cout<<result[counter]<<endl;//correct
}  /* 2 */
```

In the line marked `1`, you're storing a pointer to the underlying string data of `temp` in `result[counter]`. None of the string contents are copied; you're just storing the address of the existing data in `temp`. (By the way, what is the `(char*)` cast for? `.c_str()` already returns a pointer to `char`.)

In the line marked `2`, `temp` is destroyed (it was a local variable in this block). Now `result[counter]` contains an invalid pointer: The object it was pointing to doesn't exist anymore.

Any attempt to use the contents of `result` after this result in undefined behavior.

One way you could fix this is to use an array of strings instead of an array of pointers:

```
string result[9];
for(int counter=0;counter<9;counter++)
{
    getline(cin,result[counter]);
    cout<<result[counter]<<'\n';
}
```

(I've also removed `endl` because there is no need to explicitly flush the stream after every single string.)

This also simplifies the code a bit because you no longer need a `temp` variable: You can just `getline` directly into the array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Though I still have a question: according to what you have said, the local variable should be destroyed after the for loop, however when I print out the result array after the for loop, it gives nine 'boot' which is the last word I input, do you have any idea why?

Comment: And I used (char*) cast because by default c_str() function returns const char*.

Comment: @admin822 It's undefined behavior. It can do whatever it wants. Also, why cast away `const`? You could have just changed the type of `result` to include `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet use `std::vector<string>`

```
std::vector<std::string> result;
for(int counter=0;counter<9;counter++) {
  std::string temp;
  std::getline(std::cin, temp);
  result.push_back(temp);
}
```

If you want to use pointers, you need to copy the contents of str.c_str() as it is a temp that is destroyed after each iteration.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. But I actually know how to save several input strings and I have solved this problem with a list<string>.  I am just curious about why my original code would print the last word 'boot' nine times.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code and specifically with this line:

```
result[counter]=(char*) temp.c_str();
```

Since `temp` lives within the for loop and [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) returns an address that will be invalid once temp is destructed, your code suffers from UB.
The address is invalid because [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data):

> Returns a pointer to the underlying array serving as character storage.

Once temp is out of scope, that underlying array is gone, but you now have a reference to it outside its scope!

You should allocate new memory for each of the string in `result` maybe using [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) as in the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    char* result[9];
    for(int counter=0;counter<9;counter++)
   {
        string temp;
        getline(cin,temp);
        result[counter]=strdup(temp.c_str()); //now it is correct!
        cout<<result[counter]<<endl;
    }
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
for(int counter=0;counter<9;counter++)
    cout<<result[counter]<<endl;
}
```

Do not forget that `strdup` will allocate memory that needs to be deallocated manually.

Comment: Yeah, but now you're leaking memory and `strdup` is a non-standard function.

Answer (score 0):

In following loop you are declaring temp string and using it again and again. so in each iteration of the loop, same pointer is being edited. hence the last value stays and rest are overwritten.

```
for(int counter=0;counter<9;counter++)
   {
        string temp;
        getline(cin,temp);
        result[counter]=(char*) temp.c_str();
        cout<<result[counter]<<endl;//correct
    }
```

Instead declare your temp string outside as a string array with capacity of 9.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    char* result[9];
        string temp[9];
    for(int counter=0;counter<9;counter++)
   {
        getline(cin,temp[counter]);
        result[counter]=(char*) temp[counter].c_str();
        cout<<result[counter]<<endl;//correct
    }
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
for(int counter=0;counter<9;counter++)
    cout<<result[counter]<<endl;//false
}
```